# sqlite read back after write

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a rather baffling situation. I write to a database in an `IntentService`:

```
App.database.beginTransaction();
try {
  for (Data item : data) {
    ContentValues values = item.getValues();
    if (App.database.insertWithOnConflict(TABLE_NAME, null, values, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE) < 1)
      App.database.updateWithOnConflict(TABLE_NAME, values, "id=?", new String[] { item.id }, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);
  }
  App.database.setTransactionSuccessful();
}
catch (Exception e) {
  Log.i(TAG, e.toString());
}
finally {
  App.database.endTransaction();
}
```

with properly applied transaction calls. There are no exceptions and no rollback during the write operation. If I check the database by reading it back after this write, I get the full row count number all right: the database *is* populated.

```
Log.i(TAG, "count " + Data.getCount()); // returns correct row count
ResultReceiver receiver = intent.getParcelableExtra("receiver");
receiver.send(RESULT_INITIALIZED, null);
```

As soon as the writing finishes, the `IntentService` notifies my activity using a `ResultReceiver` that the writing operation took place.

```
private class MyResultReceiver extends ResultReceiver {

@Override
protected void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {
  Log.i(TAG, "count " + Data.getCount()); // returns zero
}
```

But, if I check my database row count again in the receiver, I get a zero, the database is empty. `Data.getCount()` simply opens a new cursor and gets the count:

```
public static int getCount() throws SQLiteException {
  Cursor cursor = App.database.query(TABLE_NAME, null, null, null, null, null, null);
  int count = cursor.getCount();
  cursor.close();
  return count;
}
```

I'm aware of the limitations of simultaneous reads and writes (and also the WAL mode) but I *don't* want them to overlap. I'd simply like to be able to populate the database in the service and act upon it in the original activity. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This has nothing to do with this problem, but you should use [queryNumEntries](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html#queryNumEntries%28android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20java.lang.String%29) instead of reading all rows.

Comment: Fair point. It was just a quick check but yes, you're right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a nasty one, after all. A `deleteDatabase()` in a different part in the app startup sequence that must have been somewhat asynchronous (its source code doesn't reveal that but still). So, the database *was* cleared before the write and the read operations, after all. Took quite some time to track it down...